# Max Open Cursors ORA-01000 using ODP.NET C# OracleDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odp.net

I am using the Oracle Data Provider for .NET version 4.112.3.0 to access an Oracle 9 database from an ASP.NET web application. Even though I explicitly `Close` and `Dispose` of the `OracleDataReader` and `OracleConnection` objects, I receive an ORA-01000 maximum open cursors exceeded error at times.

Most of my ODP.NET code is wrapped into a custom class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.Data;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyOracleClass : IDisposable
    {
        private static string connectionString = "Data Source=myDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;";
        private OracleConnection _conn;
        private OracleTransaction _txn;

        public MyOracleClass()
        {
            try
            {
                _conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
                if (_conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    _conn.Open();
                _txn = _conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log Exception
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public void Query(string query, ref OracleDataReader dr)
        {
            dr = null;
            OracleCommand cmd = null;

            try
            {
                if (_conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    _conn.Open();
                cmd = new OracleCommand(query, _conn);

                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log Exception    
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd != null)
                    cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsConnectionOpen())
                {
                    _txn.Rollback();
                    _conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log Exception
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Disconnect();

            try
            {
                if (this._txn != null)
                {
                    _txn.Dispose();
                    _txn = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log Exception
            }

            try
            {
                if (this._conn != null)
                {
                    this._conn.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log Exception
            }
        }

        public bool IsConnectionOpen()
        {
            if (this._conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I then use the class in my program.

```
public void test()
{
    OracleDataReader dr = null;
    MyOracleClass oracleDb = null;
    string query = "SELECT COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 FROM MY_TABLE";

    try
    {
        oracleDb = new MyOracleClass();
        oracleDb.Query(query, ref dr);

        if(!dr.HasRows)
        {
            // No data found
        }
        else
        {
            while(dr.Read())
            {
                // Process data
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Log Exception
    }
    finally
    {
        if(dr != null)
        {
            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
        }

        oracleDb.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My query returns an average of 500 rows. When I first experienced the issue, I decided to go to the database to see how many cursors were actually opening up. The `OPEN_CURSORS` parameter for my database is set to 100. For a given call to the query, I noticed there were 92 open cursors for this simple select query and would break the 100 cursor limit at times! Why would such a large number of cursors open when using the `OracleDataReader`?

Note, I've been testing this on a development system running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.0. I've also called the `OracleConnection.ClearAllPools` method once finished with the `OracleConnection`, but this didn't seem to help either. I also tested the query by populating a `DataTable` object by using the `Fill` method along with an `OracleDataAdapter`. Using this method only opened 3 cursors. Why is there such a variation in the number of cursors opened?

Comment: why do you need to open a transaction for a select?

Comment: @Dr.Stitch I have another method in MyOracleClass that calls ExecuteNonQuery for insert/delete/update, so the OracleTransaction is used for commits and rollbacks. I removed the code for brevity.